# Ad blocker block affiliate page on production but works fine on development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, web, web-development-server

My front-end code is written in react and back-end code is written in rails.  So when i request from frontend to affiliate controller in production it gets blocked by adblocker. Please State me the reason for it??
Also i want that problem to be get reflected in development mode. So what to do for this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because if the request url containg affiliate in the url then adblocker blocks the url. And for reflecting in development mode please use ngrok on the port 3000